# Is there a way to mute audio of a video played by vlc from command-line?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to mute a video played by vlc from command line?

I managed to only find [a single other post on a similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256193/linux-control-a-running-vlc-process-through-command-line), however, it is 8 years old and hasn't been answered in a clear yes or no fashion, which is what I'm after. edit: Also, I'm using OSX 10.14.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome (out) on SuperUser! Please [edit] your post adding the link to the Q&A you find (after the last `[1]:` that you will find in your question... and yes specify the OS you are using, it may help. You may find useful [Linux control a running vlc process through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256193/linux-control-a-running-vlc-process-through-command-line) question and answers.

Comment: BTW you can run `vlc --no-audio myvideo.avi` (this will not run audio decoding at all saving cpu), or do you want to mute a video already played by vlc?

Comment: Edited per your notes, ty, and --no-audio seems to do it, although I was looking for a non-permanent solution hence the question still stands.

Comment: your is a multiple answer question...you may still refine it... `;-)` e.g. Do you want to run from command-line vlc with _audio volume set to 0_ or do you want to change the volume level of an already running instance of vlc. Moreover you may act on the system volume output level or ... BTW `vlc --help` will give you some hints. `vlc --help | grep -i olume` can help too... `vlc -H` even more...  `vlc -H | grep -i olume` will refine it...even if volume is used in other meaning too...

Comment: You're right, the question was worded rather awkwardly. The idea is to pre-mute the file right at the start so as to avoid having to do it manually with the command-alt-down arrow hotkey. I've gone through the manual and all it lists are the bind options such as «--global-key-vol-mute <string>», which, from the sound of it, simply changes the hotkey to a different key combination.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--v4l2-audio-mute` should mute the sound on startup.

From `vlc --full-help`:

```
      --v4l2-audio-mute, --no-v4l2-audio-mute 
                                 Mute
                                 (default disabled)
          Mute the audio.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

```
vlc --aout=waveout --waveout-volume=0.00
```

The `aout` specifies the output device, it must be set as the automatic one does not appear to correctly.